# Why is resize disabled in my Ckeditor Image2 plugin

Tags: javascript, image, plugins, ckeditor

I added image2 to my ckeditor and it doesn't I cannot resize images I add.  The image properties dialog does not even show fields to change the size.  Can anyone hint at where my configurations may be restricting the plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't you set `config.allowedContent` to something incorrect like `p img`?

Comment: You got to specify `img[width,height]` in your `config.allowedContent` or `config.extraAllowedContent`.

Comment: Yes, that was it,  I had img[src,alt]{width,height}.  Changed it to img[src,alt,width,height] and it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config.allowedContent has to be set correctly. I needed **img[width,height]** to be included.

Here is a correct example:

```
config.allowedContent = 'a[!href,target];img[src,alt,width,height]; span[*](*)';
```